# How do I preload images from assets?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to preload some assets that are used in a PageView like this..

```
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    precacheImage(AssetImage("assets/images/background.png"), context)
      .then((result) {
        print('$result');
      });

    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }
```

Expected result: The result value in then() would return the preloaded image
Actual result: The result value is null

Does anyone have any examples of how preloadCache() is meant to work as the documentation for it is very poor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return value for `precacheImage` is `Future<void>` so using `then` on the result will not return the image itself.

One of the easier ways to use it is to use in the `build` method of the parent widget of widget that you want to show the image like this:

```
class ImagePage extends StatelessWidget{   
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Image.network("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/39/Periodic_table_large.png");
  }
}
```

Then, you can call `precacheImage` in the widget before you navigate to the ImagePage like such:

```
class TestWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    precacheImage(NetworkImage("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/39/Periodic_table_large.png"), context);
    return Center(
          child: RaisedButton(
        child: Text('Launch screen'),
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ImagePage()),
          );
        },
      ));
  }
}
```

This way when you press the button to launch the `ImagePage`, the image will already be loaded.

Comment: @Pagrate if you find this answer useful, can you please upvote it? Thanks :)